# Javascript return value from a function with multiple async call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is my code

```
function performComputation(Name){
    var x="";
    Promise.all([model.find({Name:Name}).exec()])
    .then(results => {
        x = doSomething(results[0]['name']);
    });

    return x;
}

function getAllComputation(data){
    var result="";
    for(var member of data){
        result=result.concat(performComputation(member['Name']));
    }
    return result;
}

getallComputation(someData);
```

My function getAllComputation is looping through data and generating multiple async operations but I want to wait and return a concatenation of all the computations , right now i am getting result as undefined because .find and dosomething are async , how can I wait for all operations to finish.

Comment: The callback to `.then` executes asynchronously. You will have to do all your work in promises.

Comment: Just a note, `Promise.all([aPromise]).then()` is identical to `aPromise.then()`..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: solved it using async.auto library.